# pandas str.split(' ', 5, expand=True) did overwrite my existing columns in dataframe. how to avoid this?

Tags: python, pandas

I split one of my dataframe columns by whitespace and added those parts into new columns. This works fine. However, what it does it overwrite my existing columns which are therefore wiped out.

How do I avoid thid?

```
df = df[['address','beds','sqft']].copy()
df=df['address'].str.split(' ', 5, expand=True)
```

Address will expand into 5 columns and will at the same time overwrite column 'beds' and 'sqft'.
Pleaser advise.

Comment: Can we see your df, please (input, actual and expected)? Likely, the solution is to specify the problems in the left hand side of your assignment, e.g. `df[["foo", "bar"]] = df["address"].str.split...`.

Comment: It didn't overwrite your existing columns, you did. `df=df['address'].str.split(..)`. reassigns your df.

Comment: `concat` the result back: `df = pd.concat([df, df['address'].str.split(' ', 5, expand=True)], axis=1)`